# Automatic pull request labels and release comments?

Tags: github

I would like to have PR's labelled with `released` / `not-yet-released`, based on, whether there exists any release, where PR is merged.

Also, when a release is created, then a comment to PR would be useful, ie.: released in version x.y.z.

So, ideally, I would expect following behavior:

- merge of PR: label with `not-yet-released`,
- release creation, for each merged, but `not-yet-released, PR:

  - label with `released`, remove `not-yet-released`,
  - add comment: released in version x.y.z,
- deletion of release, for each merged PR, which isn't released anymore:

  - label with `not-yet-released`, remove `released`,
  - add comment: release x.y.z deleted, PR isn't released.

I'll be satisfied with any partial solution though,...

Answer (score 1):

There is a GitHub app via probot that might solve some of your problem:
https://probot.github.io/apps/pr-triage/

> PR Triage
>   Add a label depending on the pull request's status